# Socket.io emit event not firing from client side

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

It may be something obvious but I don't understand why I don't receive my event in the server side

Server :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, pseudo) {
socket.on('clickOnGraph', function(){
    console.log('Reception of the first sending');
    socket.broadcast.emit('clickOnGraph')
    console.log('Broadcasting to everyone');
});
```

Client :

```
$scope.clickOnGraph = function(){
    console.log('click detected, first sending to server');
    socket.emit('clickOnGraph');
}

socket.on('clickOnGraph', function(){
    console.log('Reception of the broadcast');
    console.log('Event clickOnGraph : OK');
});
```

When I send an event from the server to the client, it works, but not the opposite...
And $scope.clickOnGraph is working.

Thank you for your help, I'm gettting crazy

Comment: Have you double checked that the client is connecting to the correct ip and port?

Comment: Yes I think so, because my server sends events to my client, and they run without any problem.

Comment: it's ok, I just had to restart the server...